# Qualify default SCHEMA for update (create temp table) via configuration of Snowflake Microstrategy

Tags: schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, temp-tables, microstrategy

My *Microstrategy* project is connected (4tiers) to a *Snowflake DB* via an DB instance and is granted (via connexio user) on 3 schemas : Data1, Data2 and Information_schema. No schema is specified in the odbc.ini of my *Microstrategy* server.

The connection is effective, but when I run multipass queries reports, I got a SQL error on the create temporary table:

> 'No schema specified, you must specify one via USE SCHEMA.

In order to not reduce the scope of schemas, I don't want to specify a Report Pre statement via the VLDB option of the DB instance.

My question is: Is there a way to qualify a default SCHEMA for update (create temp table) via the configuration of *Snowflake*: user or session or any way?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is simply prefix everything you're running. As in instead of using
`select * from table`
do a
`select * from schema.table`

this is going to give you all the precision in the world.

Other than that, you can only set a schema for all the queries you're running at a point, not just specific single type of.

Comment: Hello, hmm.

My problem is not to qualify the schema.tables I need to read via 'select * from' (Microstategy drives perfectly dynamic tables prefix) but to specify a schema for 'create volatile table'.

Regards

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to do that